# Slurpage and barfage in Clojure

Tags: vim, clojure, s-expression, paredit

I am using [vim-sexp](https://github.com/guns/vim-sexp) and [vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people) plugins for editing Clojure files. I don't quite understand what **slurp** and **barf** commands do exactly.

I tried playing with them, and it seems that they insert/remove forms at the beginning/end of an adjacent form. Is that correct? If not, what is the proper definition for **slurp** and **barf**?

Comment: Note: There is a [dedicated site for vi & vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

slurping and barfing are the essential operations/concepts to use one of the modern **structural code editors**. after getting used to them I'm completely incapable of editing code without these. Of the ~20 people that sit with me writing clojure all day *all* of them use these all the time. so saying that they are "helpful for lisp coders" is a very tactful and polite understatement.

slurp: (verb)

"to include the item to one side of the expression surrounding the point into the expression"

barf: (verb)

"to exclude either the left most or right most item in the expression surrounding the point from the expression"

and some examples.

```
1 2 (3 4) 5 6
```

slurp right:

```
1 2 (3 4 5) 6
```

barf right:

```
1 2 (3 4) 5 6
```

slurp left:

```
1 (2 3 4) 5 6
```

barf left:

```
1 2 (3 4) 5 6
```

and we're back where we started.

When I give talks/presentations introducing paredit I generally leave students/attendees with just these two concepts because I feel they are enough to start getting the benefit of structural editing without being overwhelming. Once you are comfortable with these **then move on to structual navigation** by learning to move forward/backward and up/down by expression rather than by character.

even though it list emacs keybindings I still highly recommend the animated guide to paredit that Peter Rincker mentions in his answer.

Comment: I needed your answer to finally understand it. Now it all seems obvious - as with all important things.

Comment: Could you give some link to move on to structual navigation ?

Answer (score 4):

it may seem gross, but i visualise barf-ing like vomiting (they are [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/barf?s=t) after all), where you are expelling something out.

slurping, i visualise having a drink through a straw and drawing in the drink.

The pipe symbol is the cursor in these illustrations.

so barf-ing to the right (pushing out the `4` )

```
1 2 (3 |4) 5 6 -> 1 2 (3|) 4 5 6
```

and slurping to the right gets you back the 4 (gross as it may be to re-ingest what you previously threw up)

```
1 2 (3|) 4 5 6 -> 1 2 (3 4) 5 6
```

The backward version do the same things but with items before the current s-exp.

I find I use the forward/right versions much more than the left, as I'm usually adding something in front, like a `let` binding, so a session might be:

```
(some-fn1 (count some-map))
(some-fn2 (count some-map))
```

aha, a let could come in here to refactor the `(count some-map)`:

```
(let [c (count some-map)]|)
(some-fn1 c)
(some-fn2 c)
```

But the let isn't wrapping the 2 calls, so we want to pull in (slurp) the next 2 forms inside the let s-exp, so now at the cursor position, slurp twice which will give after first:

```
(let [c (count some-map)]|
  (some-fn1 c))
(some-fn2 c)
```

and then on second:

```
(let [c (count some-map)]|
  (some-fn1 c)
  (some-fn2 c))
```

and any decent editor with paredit/structural editing will also do the indentation at the same time for you.

It's also important to note that the barf/slurp will happen within the current set of brackets (i.e. slurping `(let [a (count x)])` will do different things depending on where the cursor is, as there are 3 sets of brackets), hence why I was careful where to put the cursor in the let binding above, else you're push in/out the wrong bracket (which is another way of thinking of barf/slurping - manipulating the position of the bracket rather than pull/pushing items into/out of the s-exp).

Comment: Your metaphor leaves a lasting impression on the mind)

Comment: Anything to aid the visualization :-)

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert on: lisps, emacs, paredit, vim-sexp, or vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people. (Why am I posting right?!)

However I know that slurp and barf come form Emac's paredit mode. This Emacs mode is supposedly very helpful for lisp coders. I am sure you can find a nice helpful article on these subjects if you search for paredit. As a matter a fact I found a nice article for you: [The Animated Guide to Paredit](http://danmidwood.com/content/2014/11/21/animated-paredit.html). From what I can tell you are right in your guesses about slurp and barf.

Comment: See https://practical.li/spacemacs/structural-editing/ for "smartparens".